# Cron a database dump on an external SFTP server

Tags: backup, rsync, sftp, cron, scp

I have a command to dump a database in a local server, and want a daily backup of that database in an external SFTP location.
I checked out the `scp` command and it works smoothly, now I need (maybe using crontabs?) to setup a command which:

generate a dump and put it into a local folder
copy that dump on a remote SFTP folder
keep both the folders clean keeping just the last 7 versions of the backup
do all the above daily
What's the best practice to do this? I am a newbie on scripts and `rsync`.

Thank you!

Comment: You've tagged with [tag:rsync] and [tag:scp] but you seem to prefer `sftp`. Do you really need to use `sftp` or would `rsync` over `ssh` be an acceptable alternative? Do you have access (e.g. with `ssh`) to the remote server?